# Interpolation Search/Sort

Tags: sorting, search, interpolation

Can someone give me a quick run through of what interpolation search/sort is. I've done some searches and from my understanding it means that you can find and item based on the index of something. Can someone explain how this works? Possibly with and example?

I'm sure it's extremely simple an i'm just over thinking it. Also why is it at worst case. Linear time? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Interpolation search is a fancier version of binary search. Binary search works by finding a median index from which to recursively look for a target element.

If you were looking through a dictionary using normal binary search you would open up the dictionary at the "m" words and compare the word you are looking for and either search in the words that come before or after.

Interpolation sort gives you a better starting point and more accurately matches how people search. If you were looking for the word Aardvark in the dictionary you would not start at M but rather start at the beginning.

To find a more accurate starting median interpolation sort calculates the median with the equation:

```
m = l + (r - l) * (x * a[l]) / (a[r] - a[l])
```

where:

```
m is the midpoint
a is the array you are searching in
l is the left endpoint (ie 0)
r is the right endpoint (ie length of array)
x is the target element
```